# Twitter Fabric - Cannot Resolve Symbol

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I've installed the Twitter Fabric plugin for Android Studio. That was simple and straightforward however my project can't recognise any of the Twitter objects when I copy and paste the code from the Fabric dialogue box. For example the following line

```
private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;
```

has 'TwitterLoginButton' in red and says 'cannot resolve symbol'. I've copied the import statements already so I thought that would be it.

Obviously I haven't downloaded something or I need to make Android studio aware of a file path maybe. I've configured the setting for the Android SDK, so that's fine. Does anyone know of any common mistakes when first implementing Twitter Fabric to Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Love these simple, stupid ones. All I had to do was click Rebuild under the Build option in the toolbar to make everything ok. I assume this is due to the Gradle Build.