# Cannot get the twitter fabric dependencies using gradle

Tags: android, twitter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I cannot use the Fabric SDK in android studio.
I installed the Fabric plugin, but id does not seem to recognise my project so i intend to do it manually.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
        // quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}
```

Gradle built successful. 
but still cannot resolve the symbol `Fabric`

Comment: May be this one can help someone. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37115497/4531507

Answer (score 0):

I add this as a response as I can't add long comments. I have checked the .pom files of the maven repository. The main difference between 2.3.2 and 2.4.0/2.5.0 is that 2.4.0/2.5.0 add some exclusions to the dependency:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>crashlytics-core</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.crashlytics.sdk.android</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>crashlytics-ndk</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.crashlytics.sdk.android</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>digits</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.digits.sdk.android</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>crashlytics</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.crashlytics.sdk.android</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>beta</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.crashlytics.sdk.android</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
```

Answer (score -1):

You also have to add the dependency to your project:

```
dependencies {

    // ....

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to sync the gradle file and to use gradle clean ?

Comment: Same happening to me. It doesn't seem to import the libraries. In the java files I can't import Fabric or Crashlytics classes. Tested with 2.5.0 and 2.4.0. Latest version that seems to work ok is 2.3.2